# Android Changing Action Bar color

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to change the Action Bar color, but I don't know how to do it. What should I add to change the style?

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->

</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is all you need to change the color of the action bar:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#995544</item>
</style>
```

Comment: how about the word's color?

Comment: you can use <item name="colorPrimary">@color/green</item>.
and add to res color <color name="green">#2fb56c</color>

Comment: for changing action bar title color:
'<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MyTitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTitleTextStyle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">#232323</item>
</style>'

Comment: I wish, when people post these "solutions", they would include the location and even the name of the file, to assist those of us trying to learn the eco-system.  There are over 400 XML files in a Wizard generated project.  There are about 5-10 files with XML content at the level where the user is expected to edit them manually.

Comment: @Taurus I found it after digging around.  But Thanks.

Comment: @SpacemanScott Yeah, I knew that (it's more than a month old, after all). I commented to help future folk who might have the same question as you.

Answer (score 4):

That code works for me and it also changes text color

```
<resources>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText</item>
    <item name="background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:height">150dp</item>
    <item name="height">60dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar.TitleText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Works, but doesn't change icon color.

Answer (score 2):

If your minSdk is 21 or higher, you can add the following:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
```

---

If not then make the following changes:

1. Your activity must extend `AppCompatActivity`
2. Change your theme to `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`
3. Add this to the top of your activity xml file:

   `<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      android:elevation="4dp"
      android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
      app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>`
4. Put this in your `onCreate` method after the `super.onCreate` call:

   `Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);`
5. To change the color just replace `?attr/colorPrimary` with `@color/yourColor`

Comment: how about the word's color?

Comment: After you set the Toolbar as SupportActionBar, write 'getSupportActionBar().setTitle(0);'                                                            Then add a TextView as a child to the toolbar and change it's color.

Comment: i can use <item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>, but it only changes the bgcolor

Comment: Just do what I wrote before and change the color of the TextView

Comment: Wrong. With AppCompat you don't need API 21+ on the minSDK.

Answer (score 2):

**simple a single Line code**

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
</style
```

Here colorPrimary attribute helps you to change the color of action bar.
[For more details see this fig.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3izWF.png)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below:

```
<style name="AppCompatTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">#ff540e9e</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

At your theme.xml or/and theme.xml (dark), change the following `android:statusBarColor` which change the to status bar background color, `toolbarNavigationButtonStyle` change the back button color, `actionBarStyle` change the background and text color and `displayOptions` to show the text.

```
    <style name="Theme.Example" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/backgroundDark</item>

        <!-- action bar color. -->
        <item name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Actionbar.dark</item>
        <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo|showTitle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Actionbar.dark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
        <item name="background">@color/backgroundDark</item>
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/Actionbar.darktext</item>
        
    </style>

    <style name="Actionbar.darktext" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Toolbar.Button.Navigation.Tinted" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
        <item name="tint">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

You can customize the current theme for your app, in the res/values/styles.xml file try:

```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
         // your custom styles added to theme        
     <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
 </style>


     //Cutomise your theme by specifying layout,color, font type etc:
 <style name="MyActionBarTheme" 
        parent="@android:style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
     // sets the background color of the activity/app:  
     <item name="android:background">#33FF33</item>
 </style>
```

Then you will need to add your new custom theme name to your apps Manifest file

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.